# Generate unique hashes in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for advise about best practices of generating unique hash strings in Ruby/Rails. Usually I use MD5, SHA etc to do this, but it was not quite straightforward to choose source values for hash (timestamps not always prefered to be used).
So my question are:

1. **What values prefered to be used for generating unique hashes? (database column values, timestamps etc)**
2. **Are there any gems for this kind of work?**

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use UUIDs:

In ruby 1.9

```
require 'securerandom'
SecureRandom.uuid
```

In ruby 1.8

```
$ gem install uuidtools

UUIDTools::UUID.random_create
```

Comment: If you want a hex value: `SecureRandom.hex` gives you `eb693ec8252cd630102fd0d0fb7c3485`